# python datetime strptime wildcard

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, strptime

I want to parse dates like these into a datetime object:

- December 12th, 2008
- January 1st, 2009

The following will work for the first date:

```
datetime.strptime("December 12th, 2008", "%B %dth, %Y")
```

but will fail for the second because of the suffix to the day number ('st'). So, is there an undocumented wildcard character in strptime? Or a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the dateutil.parser module.

```
import dateutil.parser
date1 = dateutil.parser.parse("December 12th, 2008")
date2 = dateutil.parser.parse("January 1st, 2009")
```

Additional documentation can be found here: http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: python-dateutil looks to have moved. The docs are at  https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/  and there are links to it's github repo and pypi page there.

Answer (score 10):

You need Gustavo Niemeyer's [python_dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) -- once it's installed,

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('December 12th, 2008')
datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 12, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('January 1st, 2009')
datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

strptime is tricky because it relies on the underlying C library for its implementation, so some details differ between platforms.  There doesn't seem to be a way to match the characters you need to.  But you could clean the data first:

```
# Remove ordinal suffixes from numbers.
date_in = re.sub(r"(st|nd|rd|th),", ",", date_in)
# Parse the pure date.
date = datetime.strptime(date_in, "%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: I'd be worried about what this is going to do to August.

Comment: That's why I included the trailing comma.

Comment: I'd say you're better off adding

[\d]{1,2}

before your regular expression. After all you want to match suffixes after numbers, right? :-)

Comment: [\d]{1,2} will match the digits and strip them from the date as well, not very helpful!  You need a positive look behind assertion to ensure the st/nd/rd/th is preceded by a digit, but not match that digit, like this: (?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use arbitrary wildcards, you can use [datetime-glob](https://libraries.io/pypi/datetime-glob), a module we developed to parse date/times from a list of files generated by a consistent date/time formatting. From the module's documentation:

```
>>> import datetime_glob
>>> matcher = datetime_glob.Matcher(
                         pattern='/some/path/*%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ.jpg')

>>> matcher.match(path='/some/path/some-text2016-07-03T21-22-23Z.jpg')
datetime_glob.Match(year = 2016, month = 7, day = 3, 
                    hour = 21, minute = 22, second = 23, microsecond = None)

>>> match.as_datetime()
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 3, 21, 22, 23)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who, like me, just want something that "works" without an additional module, this is a quick and dirty solution.

```
string_list = ["th", "rd", "nd", "st"]
time = None
for str in string_list:
    if (time is not None):
        break
    try:
        match_string = '%B %d' + str +', %Y'
        time = datetime.strptime("December 12th, 2008", match_string)
    except Exception:
        pass
```